# How to sort the list values according to the first letter of the value in Python

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have a issue in lists. I have a `list =['randomf','decisiont','extremeg']` which is appended with another list `list2 = ['bike','age','car'],` and then sorted according it together which means each value of first list have the appended values of `list2(e.g:'randomf_bike','randomf_age' ,'randomf_car')` but when I sort it turns to be like this(e.g: `'randomf_age','randomf_bike' ,'randomf_car') Its` not only sorting according to the first letter of the value but also sorting according to the letter after '_'. How can I sort according to the first letter?

```
My code: 
list =['randomf','decisiont','extremeg'] 
list2 = ['bike','age','car']
new_list =  [el1+'_'+el2 for el2 in list2 for el1 in sorted(set(list))]
new_list = sorted(new_list)
which gives : new_list = ['decisiont_age','decisiont_bike' ,'decisiont_car','extremeg_age','extremeg_bike' ,'extremeg_car','randomf_age','randomf_bike' ,'randomf_car'] 
The excepted output is:
 new_list = ['decisiont_bike','decisiont_age' ,'decisiont_car','extremeg_bike','extremeg_age' ,'extremeg_car', 'randomf_bike','randomf_age' ,'randomf_car']
```

Comment: It's unrelated to your sorting issues, but using `list` as a variable name is a bad idea. It shadows the builtin `list` type's name, which may lead to confusing errors later on, if you try to convert something to a list (like `list(range(10))`).

Comment: @Bickknght hmm ya, but what would an another good way to do this? I am creating a model which predicts one column by column in a data frame. And this gets appended as shown above like for one algorithm with one column name which is being predicted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can give a `key` function to the call to `sorted`. If you want to sort only on the part of the string before the first `_` character, you can do `sorted(new_list, key=lambda s: s.split('_', 1)[0])`.

But you might also be able to avoid that second sort, if you assemble your compound strings in the right order from the start. I think you can just change the order of your two-level iteration and it should match what you want (you're already sorting the first list):

```
new_list =  [el1+'_'+el2 for el1 in sorted(set(list)) for el2 in list2] # change order here
# don't sort again!
```